# How to copy cell value twice in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

How can I copy values in cell twice in another column?
The values are in column A and I want them have copied in column B, like this:

```
A B
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 1
  2
  2
  3
  3
```

etc etc etc

EDIT: I saw it looks different when the question is posted, therefore I added a photo.
  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is in Column A and say in C1 onward you want each entry twice.
Put the following formula in C1 and drag it down until required.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,INT(ROW()-ROW($A2)/2)+1)
```

[image]

### Update

To solve this problem, you need to use INDEX function at a top level to get the desired cell value from column A. However in order to repeat each cell value twice, you need to come up with a sequence like 1 1 2 2 3 3 and so on and apply it in INDEX function as you increment to each cell in output column.

Starting with number 2 i.e. `=ROW($A2)` as a starting reference you first generate a sequence in increments of 0.5 by using `=ROW()-ROW($A2)/2+1`.

Now what you have is 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 and so on. All you need now is an INT function to remove the fraction and you have the required sequence as 1 1 2 2 3 3 and so on.

All this put together becomes `=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,INT(ROW()-ROW($A2)/2)+1)`  as in C1.

Below screenshot can help in further understanding.

[image]

However if your list starts in say A4 i.e. row 4 then the formula shall slightly change. The row() function get the desired sequence shall be

```
=INT((ROW()-ROW($A$4))/2+1)
```

And a more seamless formula that should work regardless of row number then would be

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,INT((ROW()-ROW($A$1))/2+1))
```

Comment: Good answer. Learnt something new from this. When you have the time just explain the logic of the formula... Super useful

Comment: Dang, props to you! I've been trying to answer this for half an hour hahaha

Comment: @Prasanna - Answer is updated to detail out the logic and further improvised it.