# Formula - autofill, but repeat a value twice

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to autofill a column in excel like so:

```
10/19/2017
10/19/2017
10/20/2017
10/20/2017
10/21/2017
10/21/2017
10/22/2017
10/22/2017
```

Notice that there are 2 of each value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a formula like this:

```
=+F2+IF(F1=F2,1,0)
```

Essentially, take the value above, and add 1 if value 2 above is the same, else add 0.

F2 would be your first date. this formula would go in F3 and copied down how far you want.

Comment: Thanks. The other answer mentioned (https://superuser.com/questions/1175188/how-to-copy-cell-value-twice-in-another-column) works as well, but this one is simpler.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as a duplicate. Post this as an answer on the linked question to earn upvotes for your simple and easy solution.